# Do mollifiers exist in dimensions higher than 1?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution

A mollifier is defined as a function $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varphi(x) dx = 1$$
2. $\varphi$ has compact support
3. $$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \varphi_\epsilon = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}} \varphi\big(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\big) = \delta_0$$

Thus we may mollify any function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by computing the convolution $f * \varphi_\epsilon$. I would like to do the same for a function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ where $m > 1$. To do this would require the mollifiers $\varphi$ to be extended to higher dimensions, that is $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ for $m > 1$.

Does such an object exist? If not, what about the three criteria above fails in higher dimensions? I could not find it in any textbooks.

Comment: What first comes to my mind is to consider in each coordinate a mollifier, meaning $\varphi = (\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_m)$, where each $\varphi_j$ is a mollifier. Clearly, the first condition translates to the integral being the vector with only the value $1$. 2) is fine too, and since 3) holds for each $\varphi_j$ it also holds for $\varphi$

Comment: @stange Thank you, this construction seems to work perfectly.

Comment: I suppose your limit is not $\varphi$ but $\delta_0$

Comment: @LL3.14 Thank you for catching that, I will correct my post.